# Gmail account import deleted all my mail

Tags: gmail, gmail-imap

I decided to migrate my old mailbox (`myemail@example.com`) to Gmail. My goal was to use Gmail to keep my email, but still send as `myemail@example.com`. So what i did :

1. Create new Gmail account `myemail@gmail.com`.
2. Set up forward on `myemail@mydomain.com` to go to `myemail@gmail.com`.
3. Went to Gmail’s Settings > Accounts and Import > Import mail and contacts.

In step 3, I typed my old email credentials and Gmail started to import my old email to gmail.

Next day when I enter Gmail account, old email is not there. I entered the old email webmail and old email is not there too!

I don't know if i'm missing something, but it seems Gmail deleted all my email from `myemail@example.com` and did not imported to `myemail@gmail.com`. It's a 10 year email history seems to be gone.

What can I do to find out what happened and hopefully, try to recover my old account email history?

Comment: First thing to check is your deleted mails: if the lost mails are there, recover them.

Comment: Sounds like you configured to download the emails off the server instead of downloading a copy (POP3).  As for where the emails went, make sure you are viewing all emails, by default Google Mail only displays recent emails.  In order to recover the emails, I suggest recovering, from a backup of the server itself

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you but i really can't find the old email anywhere in the new Gmail account. It has about 50 emails only, those i received after setup forward in the old account. It seems i really lost all the old email :/